# Rake test - creates YAML error, how do I fix this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml, rake-test

When running a Rake test, I get some errors referring to the YAML file.  Any ideas on how to fix it?

> Running tests: EEEEEEEE
>
> Finished tests in 0.070970s, 112.7237 tests/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.
>
> 1) Error: test_should_create_product(ProductsControllerTest):
>   ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError: a YAML error occurred parsing
>   /Users/ka/src/ruby-test/depot/test/fixtures/products.yml. Please note
>   that YAML must be consistently indented using spaces. Tabs are not
>   allowed. Please have a look at yaml.org/faq.html The exact error was:
>   Psych::SyntaxError: (): found character that cannot start any token
>   while scanning for the next token at line 5 column 1
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures/file.rb:43:in rows'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures/file.rb:29:ineach'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:670:in
>   block (2 levels) in read_fixture_files'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures/file.rb:20:inopen'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:669:in
>   block in read_fixture_files'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:668:in
>   each'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:668:in
>   read_fixture_files'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:548:in
>   initialize'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:482:in
>   new'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:482:in
>   block (2 levels) in create_fixtures'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:479:in
>   map'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:479:in
>   block in create_fixtures'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:168:in disable_referential_integrity'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:476:in
>   create_fixtures'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:895:in
>   load_fixtures'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:849:in
>   setup_fixtures'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:429:in
>   _run__2260432841310236767__setup__3358002533217195166__callbacks' /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in
>   __run_callback' /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in
>   _run_setup_callbacks' /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in
>   run_callbacks'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/testing/setup_and_teardown.rb:35:in
>   `run'
>
> 2) Error: test_should_destroy_product(ProductsControllerTest):
>   ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError: a YAML error occurred parsing
>   /Users/ka/src/ruby-test/depot/test/fixtures/products.yml. Please note
>   that YAML must be consistently indented using spaces. Tabs are not
>   allowed. Please have a look at ://www.yaml.org/faq.html The exact
>   error was: Psych::SyntaxError: (): found character that cannot start
>   any token while scanning for the next token at line 5 column 1
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures/file.rb:43:in rows'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures/file.rb:29:ineach'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:670:in
>   block (2 levels) in read_fixture_files'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures/file.rb:20:inopen'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:669:in
>   block in read_fixture_files'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:668:in
>   each'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:668:in
>   read_fixture_files'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:548:in
>   initialize'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:482:in
>   new'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:482:in
>   block (2 levels) in create_fixtures'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:479:in
>   map'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:479:in
>   block in create_fixtures'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:168:in disable_referential_integrity'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:476:in
>   create_fixtures'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:895:in
>   load_fixtures'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:849:in
>   setup_fixtures'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:429:in
>   _run__2260432841310236767__setup__3358002533217195166__callbacks' /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in
>   __run_callback' /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in
>   _run_setup_callbacks' /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in
>   run_callbacks'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/testing/setup_and_teardown.rb:35:in
>   `run'
>
> 3) Error: test_should_get_edit(ProductsControllerTest):
>   ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError: a YAML error occurred parsing
>   /Users/ka/src/ruby-test/depot/test/fixtures/products.yml. Please note
>   that YAML must be consistently indented using spaces. Tabs are not
>   allowed. Please have a look at ://www.yaml.org/faq.html The exact
>   error was: Psych::SyntaxError: (): found character that cannot start
>   any token while scanning for the next token at line 5 column 1
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures/file.rb:43:in rows'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures/file.rb:29:ineach'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:670:in
>   block (2 levels) in read_fixture_files'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures/file.rb:20:inopen'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:669:in
>   block in read_fixture_files'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:668:in
>   each'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:668:in
>   read_fixture_files'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:548:in
>   initialize'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:482:in
>   new'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:482:in
>   block (2 levels) in create_fixtures'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:479:in
>   map'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:479:in
>   block in create_fixtures'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:168:in disable_referential_integrity'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:476:in
>   create_fixtures'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:895:in
>   load_fixtures'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:849:in
>   setup_fixtures'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:429:in
>   _run__2260432841310236767__setup__3358002533217195166__callbacks' /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in
>   __run_callback' /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in
>   _run_setup_callbacks' /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in
>   run_callbacks'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/testing/setup_and_teardown.rb:35:in
>   `run'
>
> 4) Error: test_should_get_index(ProductsControllerTest):
>   ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError: a YAML error occurred parsing
>   /Users/ka/src/ruby-test/depot/test/fixtures/products.yml. Please note
>   that YAML must be consistently indented using spaces. Tabs are not
>   allowed. Please have a look at ://www.yaml.org/faq.html The exact
>   error was: Psych::SyntaxError: (): found character that cannot start
>   any token while scanning for the next token at line 5 column 1
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures/file.rb:43:in rows'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures/file.rb:29:ineach'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:670:in
>   block (2 levels) in read_fixture_files'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures/file.rb:20:inopen'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:669:in
>   block in read_fixture_files'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:668:in
>   each'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:668:in
>   read_fixture_files'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:548:in
>   initialize'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:482:in
>   new'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:482:in
>   block (2 levels) in create_fixtures'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:479:in
>   map'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:479:in
>   block in create_fixtures'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:168:in disable_referential_integrity'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:476:in
>   create_fixtures'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:895:in
>   load_fixtures'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:849:in
>   setup_fixtures'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:429:in
>   _run__2260432841310236767__setup__3358002533217195166__callbacks' /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in
>   __run_callback' /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in
>   _run_setup_callbacks' /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in
>   run_callbacks'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/testing/setup_and_teardown.rb:35:in
>   `run'
>
> 5) Error: test_should_get_new(ProductsControllerTest):
>   ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError: a YAML error occurred parsing
>   /Users/ka/src/ruby-test/depot/test/fixtures/products.yml. Please note
>   that YAML must be consistently indented using spaces. Tabs are not
>   allowed. Please have a look at ://www.yaml.org/faq.html The exact
>   error was: Psych::SyntaxError: (): found character that cannot start
>   any token while scanning for the next token at line 5 column 1
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures/file.rb:43:in rows'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures/file.rb:29:ineach'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:670:in
>   block (2 levels) in read_fixture_files'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures/file.rb:20:inopen'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:669:in
>   block in read_fixture_files'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:668:in
>   each'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:668:in
>   read_fixture_files'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:548:in
>   initialize'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:482:in
>   new'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:482:in
>   block (2 levels) in create_fixtures'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:479:in
>   map'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:479:in
>   block in create_fixtures'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:168:in disable_referential_integrity'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:476:in
>   create_fixtures'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:895:in
>   load_fixtures'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:849:in
>   setup_fixtures'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:429:in
>   _run__2260432841310236767__setup__3358002533217195166__callbacks' /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in
>   __run_callback' /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in
>   _run_setup_callbacks' /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in
>   run_callbacks'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/testing/setup_and_teardown.rb:35:in
>   `run'
>
> 6) Error: test_should_show_product(ProductsControllerTest):
>   ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError: a YAML error occurred parsing
>   /Users/ka/src/ruby-test/depot/test/fixtures/products.yml. Please note
>   that YAML must be consistently indented using spaces. Tabs are not
>   allowed. Please have a look at ://www.yaml.org/faq.html The exact
>   error was: Psych::SyntaxError: (): found character that cannot start
>   any token while scanning for the next token at line 5 column 1
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures/file.rb:43:in rows'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures/file.rb:29:ineach'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:670:in
>   block (2 levels) in read_fixture_files'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures/file.rb:20:inopen'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:669:in
>   block in read_fixture_files'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:668:in
>   each'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:668:in
>   read_fixture_files'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:548:in
>   initialize'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:482:in
>   new'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:482:in
>   block (2 levels) in create_fixtures'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:479:in
>   map'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:479:in
>   block in create_fixtures'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:168:in disable_referential_integrity'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:476:in
>   create_fixtures'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:895:in
>   load_fixtures'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:849:in
>   setup_fixtures'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:429:in
>   _run__2260432841310236767__setup__3358002533217195166__callbacks' /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in
>   __run_callback' /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in
>   _run_setup_callbacks' /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in
>   run_callbacks'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/testing/setup_and_teardown.rb:35:in
>   `run'
>
> 7) Error: test_should_update_product(ProductsControllerTest):
>   ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError: a YAML error occurred parsing
>   /Users/ka/src/ruby-test/depot/test/fixtures/products.yml. Please note
>   that YAML must be consistently indented using spaces. Tabs are not
>   allowed. Please have a look at ://www.yaml.org/faq.html The exact
>   error was: Psych::SyntaxError: (): found character that cannot start
>   any token while scanning for the next token at line 5 column 1
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures/file.rb:43:in rows'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures/file.rb:29:ineach'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:670:in
>   block (2 levels) in read_fixture_files'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures/file.rb:20:inopen'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:669:in
>   block in read_fixture_files'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:668:in
>   each'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:668:in
>   read_fixture_files'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:548:in
>   initialize'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:482:in
>   new'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:482:in
>   block (2 levels) in create_fixtures'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:479:in
>   map'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:479:in
>   block in create_fixtures'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:168:in disable_referential_integrity'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:476:in
>   create_fixtures'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:895:in
>   load_fixtures'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:849:in
>   setup_fixtures'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:429:in
>   _run__2260432841310236767__setup__3358002533217195166__callbacks' /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in
>   __run_callback' /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in
>   _run_setup_callbacks' /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in
>   run_callbacks'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/testing/setup_and_teardown.rb:35:in
>   `run'
>
> 8) Error: test_should_get_index(StoreControllerTest):
>   ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError: a YAML error occurred parsing
>   /Users/ka/src/ruby-test/depot/test/fixtures/products.yml. Please note
>   that YAML must be consistently indented using spaces. Tabs are not
>   allowed. Please have a look at ://www.yaml.org/faq.html The exact
>   error was: Psych::SyntaxError: (): found character that cannot start
>   any token while scanning for the next token at line 5 column 1
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures/file.rb:43:in rows'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures/file.rb:29:ineach'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:670:in
>   block (2 levels) in read_fixture_files'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures/file.rb:20:inopen'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:669:in
>   block in read_fixture_files'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:668:in
>   each'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:668:in
>   read_fixture_files'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:548:in
>   initialize'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:482:in
>   new'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:482:in
>   block (2 levels) in create_fixtures'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:479:in
>   map'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:479:in
>   block in create_fixtures'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:168:in disable_referential_integrity'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:476:in
>   create_fixtures'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:895:in
>   load_fixtures'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:849:in
>   setup_fixtures'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:429:in
>   _run__3541484041722071485__setup__3358002533217195166__callbacks' /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in
>   __run_callback' /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in
>   _run_setup_callbacks' /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in
>   run_callbacks'
>   /Users/ka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/testing/setup_and_teardown.rb:35:in
>   `run'
>
> 8 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 8 errors, 0 skips Errors running
>   test:units! # Errors running test:functionals! #

Comment: What does `/Users/ka/src/ruby-test/depot/test/fixtures/products.yml` look like?  Does it contain tabs instead of spaces?

Comment: This error seems pretty straightforward: "Please note that YAML must be consistently indented using spaces. Tabs are not allowed." `products.yml` file probably contains some tabs.

Comment: Thanks, it was some tabs that did it..

Answer (score 17, accepted):

open your `products.yml` file and in that see there is no extra spaces before and after word
all are in one line as one:

```
 title: MyString
description: MyText
image_url: MyString
price: 9.99
```

then it gives error "no space before title", it must be
one:

```
title: MyString
description: MyText
image_url: MyString
price: 9.99
```

Comment: Also make sure you are using spaces instead of tabs in your YML file.  Validate your YML with a linter like this: http://www.yamllint.com/